# Detecting FlatList scroll direction on React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to animate a card to slide up to take the full view when I start scrolling down and slide back down when I scroll up but I don't know how to detect the scroll direction of the FlatList.

How can I detect FlatList scroll direction using a functional component? I think it can be done using `onScroll` with `contentOffset.y` but I'm not sure how to implement it.

`<FlatList onScroll={(event)=> event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y....?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it like this:

```js
// YOUR imports
var currentOffset = 0;
export class YourView extends Component {
// ...
onScroll={(event) => {
    let direction = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y > currentOffset ? 'down' : 'up';
    currentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    console.log(direction); // up or down accordingly
}}
```

Working Example [here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/flatlist-scroll-example).

Run it on your Physical Device or Android/iOS to see results.

**Note:** Changed state usage and replaced with a var, to prevent state updates on every `onScroll` event.

Comment: This is not a good answer as you are updating the state every time you scroll, which consequently forces new renderings. If possible, provide a solution that doesn't render the component numerous times! Some approach using let variables instead states turns your answer a good way